# USB drive is recognized but not mounted

Tags: usb-flash-drive, mount, arch-linux

The flash drive is recognized as shown by `/var/log/messages.log`:

```
Jul 12 10:58:41 phelps kernel: [ 5865.612777] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
```

But I can't find its dev file in `/dev` or `/dev/disk/by-id` or `/dev/disk/by-uuid`. What could be the problem？

By the way, I am using the latest Archlinux. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be there as `/dev/sdx`, at least that's what it's like on my Ubuntu install.

Comment: There isn't any additional /dev/sd* besides my own hard drive. Interestingly, I can mount the usb drive in the Windows virtual machine inside my Archlinux box.

Comment: @RNAer umm, is there any /dev/hd*?

Comment: no /dev/hd* either

Comment: try `rmmod ehci_hcd` and `modprobe ehci_hcd` as seen in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114077

Comment: `rmmod ehci_hcd` ran but `modprobe ehci_hcd` gave error with code 1. Still not mounted.

Comment: unlikely, but possible: maybe some UDEV rule missing?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a phone (as it was in my case) change your settings from MTP mode to MSC mode.
See: [MTP or MSC](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/162/~/mtp-or-msc)